# Get size of vector elements at compile time (even if it is empty) using the Visual Studio compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Given a `std::vector` of elements of some type, how can I determine the size of the type of those elements at compile time using the Visual Studio compiler. Using `sizeof` on the first element is not an option as the vector could be empty.

For clang and gcc I can do something like this:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
size_t size_of_vector_elements(std::vector<T> vector)
{
    return sizeof(T);
}


int square(int num)
{
    std::vector<unsigned> vector;
    return size_of_vector_elements(vector);
}
```

Using O2 this will be optimized at compile time to just return 4. MSVC however cannot optimize this.Is there a way to change this code to make it possible?

Comment: You want to change to code in such a way that MSVC can optimize like GCC?

Comment: @George I am not asking the the number of elements but rather the size of the type of the elements.

Comment: @P.W Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do. The function in it's optimized form should simply return 4.

Comment: The argument to `sizeof` is not evaluated - `sizeof(vector[0])` would be equivalent to `sizeof(unsigned)`. What do you need the function for?

Comment: @JeromeReinländer: Do you think this is a duplicate of the linked post?

Comment: @P.W It kind of is, but the best answer given (in my opinion) is the one about the parameter of `sizeof` not being evaluated, as it results in the smallest and easiest to read code. This answer however is only at the very bottom of that question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want MSVC to generate optimized code for the `square` function that is similar to what GCC generates, you will have to modify your code.

You can do away with the function template `size_of_vector_elements` and make use of the fact that [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) [does not evaluate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Unevaluated_expressions) its operand.

Then your modified square function simply becomes this:

```
int square(int num)
{
    std::vector<unsigned> vector;
    return sizeof(vector[0]);
}
```

The assembly that MSVC produces for this function at `/O2` optimization is:

```
int square(int) PROC                                    ; square, COMDAT
        mov     eax, 4
        ret     0
int square(int) ENDP
```

which is similar to what GCC produces at `-O2` optimization.

```
square(int):
        mov     eax, 4
        ret
```

See [**godbolt demo.**](https://godbolt.org/z/rSfPhX)

Answer (score 7):

In c++11 or later you can use `decltype(vect)::value_type` to get type of elements in `std::vector`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> vect;
    std::cout << sizeof(decltype(vect)::value_type); // gives you sizeof(double)
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Using sizeof on the first element is not an option as the vector could be empty.

It doesn't matter if the vector is empty or not. `sizeof` does not emit any code whatsoever. This is completely fine, for example:

```
int* ptr = nullptr;
sizeof(*ptr);
```

Thus, this is perfectly fine too:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(vector<T> vec)
{
    sizeof(vec[0]);
}
```

In fact, you could even do:

```
sizeof(vec[9999999999])
```

There's not going to be any element access.

However, with that being said, it's also possible to use the `vector::value_type` alias for the element type:

```
sizeof(decltype(vec)::value_type)
```

Whether or not that's clearer code or not, I'm not sure. Up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a simple struct like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct SizeGetter
{
  typename T::value_type s;
  enum Enum
  {
    Size = sizeof(s)
  };
};
```

and use it to get desired size:

```
int s = SizeGetter<std::vector<double>>::Size;
```

or

```
static_assert(SizeGetter<std::vector<double>>::Size == 8, "Size is wrong!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a compile-time function which works with anything that has a `begin` member function:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
constexpr std::size_t getElementSize(const T &c)
{
    return sizeof(std::decay_t<decltype(*c.begin())>);
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afec7b9421825226)